# Yii framewok gridview filter dropdownbox with mulitple checkbox

Tags: yii

I am currenty working on zii.widgets.grid.CGridView and I want to show status field with multiple checkbox  in dropdownbox to search status

so there should be checkbox in dropdownbox with multi select

currently I am getting result as below image[image]

but want to replace with multiple checkbox in dropdownbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Multiselect box as your filter.

A good way to do that, is with [echmultiselect](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/echmultiselect/), which uses the [jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#filter).

This is how to use it as a filter in your CGridView:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    ....
    'columns' => array (
        'firstColumn',
        'secondColumn',
        // use EchMultiSelect for the next column
        array (
            'name'=>'thirdColumn',
            'filter'=> $this->widget('ext.EchMultiSelect.EchMultiSelect', array(
                'model' => $model,
                'dropDownAttribute' => 'thirdColumn',
                'data' => $colors,
                'options' => array('buttonWidth' => 80, 'ajaxRefresh' => true),
            ),
            true // capture output; needed so the widget displays inside the grid
        ),
    ),
));
```

Example from the [echmultiselect extension page](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/echmultiselect/#hh5), where you can also find out how you may configure your model and controller.

Comment: not working as expected: showing jquery easing error on my case. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62064671/yii-echmultiselect-showing-error-on-console-and-not-working

Comment: any solution to fix that? I've added the extension and my layout contains the jquery and jquery.ui load like `<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery');
          Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery.ui');
    ?>`