# Yii echmultiselect showing error on console and not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii

I was following the **Option no 3** here https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/echmultiselect#3-use-as-a-filter-in-cgridview to add multiselect dropdown on my Yii project. But it is showing,

> jquery.js:6920 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.easing[this.easing] is not a
>   function
>       at init.run (jquery.js:6920)

On my **cgridview**, this is the column that has to be multiple select checkbox,

```
array (
                'name'=>'brand_id',
                'filter'=> $this->widget('ext.EchMultiSelect.EchMultiSelect', array(
                    'model' => $model,
                    'dropDownAttribute' => 'brand_id',
                    'data' => CHtml::listData(Brands::model()->findAll(array("order" => "sortOrder")), 'id', 'name'),
                    'options' => array('buttonWidth' => 80, 'ajaxRefresh' => true,'filter'=>true),
                ),
                    true // capture output; needed so the widget displays inside the grid
                ),
           ),
```

On my **layout**,

I've included the jquery,

```
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery'); ?>
```

**Dropdown page:**

[image]

Because of that jQuery.easing[this.easing] is not a function error the multi-select functionality is not working, as per the suggestion here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12592301/1138192 I've added the jquery UI also but it doesn't work even it breaks the existing dropdown.

**Error on the console:**

[image]

Comment: Did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18246399/2346308

Comment: Yes, my jquery and jquery.ui version is above 1.11.1, I added that on my layout file using `<?php
          Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery');
          Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery.ui');
    ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `jquery.multiselect.js` ([EchMultiSelect-v1.3](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/echmultiselect/files/EchMultiSelect-v1.3..zip)) as the effect method arguments are [inverted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62102428/2346308) (at least for the current jQuery version):

`.show( effect, speed )` and `.hide( effect, speed )` on lines 566, 573, 600 should be replaced by the correct order `.show( speed, effect )` and `.hide( speed, effect )`.

Comment: Let me check that sir, if any issues arises I'll comment. Actually my jquery version is 1.11.1 and jquery.ui loaded via this multiselect widget is 1.11.2

Comment: As per you suggested changed on `jquery.multiselect.js` the jquery.easing issue gone but now it is showing `jquery-ui.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: this._destroy is not a function` do I need to include **jquery.ui.min.js** because currently I added only the jquery on my layout using `<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery');   ?>`

Comment: One thing to inform you If I add **jquery.ui.min** manually then the dropdown filter gone after 1 time filtering. So I guess I don't need to include that **jquery.ui.min** file but now only thing I need to remove that console error `jquery-ui.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: this._destroy is not a function`, everything else is ok after your suggested changes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've tried to modify on **assets/jquery.multiselect.js**, make the following changes also as per the suggestion here: https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/echmultiselect#c12023 but no luck

Comment: I suspect the `jquery.ui.widget.min.js` interacts in a strange way with `jquery-ui` as it's taken from jquery-ui, but from a 6 years old version

Comment: to find the cause for the jquery-ui error, I'd use the browser's degugger to trace the call back to echmultiselect.

Comment: basically it calls to this line `$.Widget.prototype.destroy.call( this );` on jquery.multiselect.js file